# Which jar for interface HttpSessionListener?

Tags: java, jar, wsdl, java2wsdl

I wanted to use `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` interface in my project. The project can't find a proper jar.

Which jar do I need to include in the project? Which package?

**Edit**

Seems like a different problem, [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458106/how-to-use-java2wsdl-on-a-class-that-implements).

Comment: Depends on package,, try servlet-api.jar

Comment: My project Java Build Path contains: /Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check if jar is present at above path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `servlet-api.jar` will do it.

and if project still can't find a proper jar, then you must try to add it again [as you have said that you are using eclispe so you can add it using `properties-> build path -> configure build path -> add external jars`].

Comment: it works for me, i have just tried after reading your question.

Comment: My project Java Build Path contains: /Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar. But it doesn't work.

Comment: i am using the same(with tomcat), it is working for me. have you copy pasted it to the lib folder or included using build path? because it is the only other jar file which is needed, so please check whether this file is there or not, and please include it using build path

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what else you need and what you have lying around. Or which container you are using.
See http://findjar.com/class/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html